# Simpler aggregate function in postgres select query

Tags: sql, postgresql, variables, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I have to run a few calculations in my select query to get dynamic values for something like profit received on a sold inventory item. The formula goes `(price minus discounts) - (total expenses) = profit`

My query works fine but I have a lot of lines like this so it's completely unreadable for anyone else. Is there a way to assign variables or something to my various aggregate functions or casts?

Here's a simpler version of my query:

```
select
    ...
    (sum(cast(ti.price as integer)) - sum(floor(cast(ti.discount as float)))) - sum(cast("exp".price as integer))) as profit,
    ...
from inventory as inv
    left join transaction_item as ti on ti.inventory_id = inv.id
    left join expense as exp on exp.inventory_id = inv.id
    ...
where
    ...
group by inv.id
```

For context:

- `ti` is a `transaction_item` table (`price` and `discount` are text
  columns)
- `inv` is an inventory items table
- `exp` is an expenses table
  (`price` is a text column)

What I'd like to do instead of that long function chain:

```
((price_total - total_discounts) - total_expenses) as profit
```

...Where I define each of those variables somewhere. Is this possible or do I need to just accept that this query will be messy?

Comment: What's with all those casts? What are the types of the columns? [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables (paste the **text**, don't use images), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: Consider [common table expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) to hold prior assignment / calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can produce computed columns that have a name and type using CTEs (Common Table Expressions). Then, you can use them in subsequent CTEs, or in the main query.

The example below defines a CTE named `inv_total` that we later use in the main query. This CTE has three computed columns `price_total`, `total_discounts`, and `total_expenses`:

```
with
inv_total as ( -- first we define a CTE
  select
    ...
    sum(cast(ti.price as integer)) as price_total,
    sum(floor(cast(ti.discount as float))) as total_discount,
    sum(cast("exp".price as integer)) as total_expenses
    ...
  from inventory as inv
    left join transaction_item as ti on ti.inventory_id = inv.id
    left join expense as exp on exp.inventory_id = inv.id
    ...
  where
    ...
  group by inv.id
)
select -- now the main query uses the CTE
  price_total - total_discounts - total_expenses as profit
from inv_total;
```

You can chain CTEs in multiple steps (separating them by commas) to compute temp values and continue the processing. The example above has a single step.

Comment: This'll do. Thanks! Using it in conjunction with COALESCE is working perfectly.